# Conflict between Lightbox and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, lightbox, conflict

I have researched thoroughly for solutions for this issues but could not find anything since I don't use `$` tags.

Actually I tried to put Lightbox on my page and a JavaScript slideshow, but it seems like only the slideshow would work and the lightbox gets disabled when I add both.

```js
<link href="css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
```

My JavaScript slideshow

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

    var Image = new Array("images/food1.jpg", "images/food2.jpg", "images/food3.jpg");

    var Image_Number = 0;
    var Image_Length = Image.length - 1;

    function change_image(num) {
        Image_Number = Image_Number + num;

        if (Image_Number > Image_Length) {
            Image_Number = 0;
        }

        if (Image_Number < 0) {
            Image_Number = Image_Length;    
        }

        document.slideshow.src= Image[Image_Number];    

        return false;
    }

    function auto() {
        setInterval("change_image(1)", 3000);
    }
</script>

//lightbox: importing the lightbox

<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js">;</script>
<script src="js/lightbox-2.6.min.js">;</script>
```

Comment: Where is the exact question? What's going wrong, is there an error message?

Comment: There is no error message but seems like there is a conflict between the scripts. In this case the javascript slideshow works but the lightbox doesn't.   If I put them individually without the other, they work perfectly though.  There is just a problem when I insert both of them in the code

Comment: Be patient, it's only volunteers helping out here in their free time. And the more detail you provide, the easier it is to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I did not went detail on your code, but that simpton you discribed seems like you are having a script conflict, a rule is that if you can only call a script once in your website here I'll give you an example of an issue I had... so just call a script once for as many plugins or modules using the script...

In the HTML codes, please remove the line marked by red. It's because the jQuery has already been added in the header section.